# How to set a column autosized, but non-responsive with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with 2 columns. The table itself is responsive.

Since usually a row is not filled-up with text (space remains) the extra-space is distributed on both columns.

I want to have the left column as wide as it needs for its content and put the rest including the non-used space to the right column. The reason is that the right column's content changes, while the left column's content is fixed. Distributing the non-used space to both columns let the right column jump with no reason for it. But I cannot express the width of the left column in grid, percent or pixel.

I'm pretty sure that I knew a very easy solution for that simply with html and css. But I'm not remembering it now.

The code has nothing special. Simply take into account, that it contains mustache to fill the right column. Replace it with content whatever you want.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>{{company.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Department</td>
    <td>{{department.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tags</td>
    <td>
      <!-- this is replaced with a list of tags -->
      {{#associatedTags}}
       <span class="tag">{{name}}<a href="…" role="button">⊗</a>
       </span>
      {{/associatedTags}}
    </td>
  <tr>
    …
  <tr>
</table>
```

As you can imagine, adding a tag to the tags row makes the content longer. As a result the right column gets more width. Its left border moves to the left shrinking the extra space on the left column. This looks ugly, because it shows a move without having a non-technical reason for it.

[image: Column Moving]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sorry, did it. As you can see, it is pretty default.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your goal. You don't want to allow the left column to wrap if needed (eventhough the example doensn't have labels that would wrap)? You don't want the left column to get too narrow, and yet "as wide as it needs for its content"? Can you clarify how it "looks ugly" and what the desired result is?

Comment: I don't want to allow the left column to become wider than it needs regardless whether there is unused spaced in the row. The whole unused space shall go to the right column. I added a screenshot. The space between the leftmost and the right lines should always be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, although it's not specific to Bootstrap.

```
.table tr td:first-child {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/OVeCpnFY7Q

Comment: Great! Exactly. I thought, that the solution is not specific to bootstrap, but wanted to include that in my Q.

Answer (score 0):

Some code will be usefull. Anyway, you could add an extra class for your row and add the following CSS:

```css
.extraclass > .col {
  background-color: #FABABA;
  width: 200px !important; /* set the desired width */
}
```

```html
<div class"container">
  <div class="row extraclass">
    <div class="col">
      example text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I cannot say, what width to set in pixels.